# What should I know when optimizing NEON code for armv8a vs armv7a?

Tags: gcc, optimization, arm, neon

I have experience with SSE and searching if ARM platforms have optimization tricks or if it just ends up on properly utilizing instruction latency and throughput?

I tried comparing armv8a to armv7a NEON but so far my searches tell me that both units are pretty similar, am I wrong on this?

Few things I could find is that:

1. armv8a have scalar NEON operations;
2. armv8a NEON shares status flag with CPU;
3. armv8a has wider registers and new instructions;
4. it's possible to use chain of one-cycle MACs with fast path;

Some specifics of the question:

1. What kind of armv8a NEON constructs perform fast?
2. What kind of armv8a NEON constructs perform slowly and should be avoided?
3. What optimization technics armv8a NEON provides (is there anything else besides chain of MACs with fast path?)?
4. How armv7a NEON compares to armv8a NEON?
5. Are there any substantial differences in how you should write high-performance code for both architectures (armv7a, armv8a)?
6. Is there a possibility that fast armv7a code performs slowly on armv8a (and vice-versa)? Some examples?
7. In what ways Snapdragon 810 influences all of the above?

Interested in both optimizations for fixed point as well as in float point.

I use gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler.

Comment: There's quite a nice comparison between v7 and v8 in [this blog](http://community.arm.com/groups/android-community/blog/2015/03/27/arm-neon-programming-quick-reference), and a bit of useful information in [its follow-up](http://community.arm.com/groups/android-community/blog/2015/03/27/arm-neon-optimization)

Comment: Here's what I've gathered so far as changes in ARMv8 versus ARMv7: 1) No additional latency for moving data between ARM and NEON registers. 2) 32 "Q" and 32 "R" registers allows more creative optimization. 3) Manual prefetch is no longer needed. 4) 32-bit and 64-bit code seems to perform similarly on SD810, 5) NVidia K1 Denver uses a custom Cortex-A57 core and performs about 50% faster than SD810 for the same clock speed (better out-of-order execution and pipelining AFAIK).